# Check if block uses personalization

Tags: episerver

Is it possible to programmatically determine if the content of a block uses personalization?

I need to know in order to handle caching correctly when the content of a block can be personalized for different visitor groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make decision about personalization you will need to get access to `ContentAreaItem` instance itself.

The most easiest way to get access to `ContentAreaItem` is to hook into rendering pipeline. You may need to swap out `ContentAreaRenderer` (see AlloyTech sample site for code snippet) with your own implementation.

Then you can implement `BeforeRenderContentAreaItemStartTag`:

```
public class MyCustomContentAreaRenderer : ContentAreaRenderer
{
    protected override void BeforeRenderContentAreaItemStartTag(TagBuilder tagBuilder, ContentAreaItem contentAreaItem)
    {
        var isPersonalizationApplied = contentAreaItem.AllowedRoles.Any();
    }
}
```

Next question of course is how you will deliver this decision down to block type instance, as overridden `ContentAreaRenderer` method is far enough from the block instance inside content area.

Comment: Do you know of a way of actually checking to see if the ContentAreaItem has been assigned a role that the user belongs to? So more than just checking to see if `contentAreaItem.AllowedRoles.Any()`, it would actually do some comparison checking there.

Answer (score 0):

@keithl8041, you can use `VisitorGroupHelper` to check whether current user matches particular role:

```
using EPiServer.Personalization.VisitorGroups;
using EPiServer.Security;


protected override void BeforeRenderContentAreaItemStartTag(TagBuilder tagBuilder, ContentAreaItem contentAreaItem)
{
    var groupHelper = new VisitorGroupHelper();
    var isPersonalizationApplied = contentAreaItem.AllowedRoles.Any();

    var isCurrentUserInAnyOfGroups = contentAreaItem.AllowedRoles.Any(r => groupHelper.IsPrincipalInGroup(PrincipalInfo.CurrentPrincipal, r);

}
```